# Understanding pointers. What does *((char **) equal to?

Tags: c, pointers

In C, I have:

```
char *p, *q;
p = malloc(1);  //for the purpose testing only
p[0] = '!';
q = *((char **)p);
printf("p=%x q=%x\n", p, q);
printf("p=%c q=%c\n", p, q);
```

There were no casting warnings, and the output is:

```
p=1a9008 q=21
p q=!
```

What happens in the expression assigned to `q`, ie `*((char **)p)`?  Has the type of `q` changed after the assignment?

---

Edits: there is an error in my code. While trying to distil it from a code fragment I came across into a fully working example, I wrongly used an example value of type char for p. After examining more of the original code, p was assigned a pointer value.  So p is a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: When a programmer is using a cast they are usually doing something wrong

Comment: That line is basically nonsense - it invokes **undefined behaviour**.

Comment: Thanks to all. It was some code I found and was trying to figure out what it was doing. (I am a novice in C.)

Comment: 'some code I found' - lose it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the type of a variable can't change, if it's declared as `char* q` then its type is `char*`.

What can change its the value of the variable but in your situation the code is simply wrong.

First `p` is declared as a pointer to a `char` and a single byte is allocated through malloc so you'll have something like

```
p = 0xDEADBEEF
        |
        ---> '!'
```

then through the cast you force `p` to be considered a `char**`, so a pointer to a pointer to a char, what happens is that the compiler is forced to consider

```
p = 0xDEADBEEF
        |
        -----> 0x??????21
                    |
                    --------> char
```

So basically you are coercing memory manually allocated and assigned to be interpreted as a memory address, then you dereference this pointer to pointer, so that `*(char**)` yields a `char*` which is the `0x??????21`, so it makes no sense.

Comment: trying to consider a non-`char *` as a `char *` causes undefined behaviour right off the bat (strict aliasing rule). The compiler isn't forced to try and make an address and follow it; that's just an artifact of the compiler generating the same assembly as it would for accessing an actual `char *`  and assuming you would never do this for a non-`char *`.